# Command line user does not have read and write permissions on var/generation directory

Tags: magento2

> Command line user does not have read and write permissions on
>   generated directory. Please address this issue before using Magento
>   command line.

I getting above error while run below comands:-

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Please help me how can I resolve this issue. Please help me.**

Answer (score 3):

If you would just read [Magento's documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/composer.html#set-file-permissions)

**Set file permissions**

You must set read-write permissions for the web server group **before** you install the Magento software. This is necessary so that the Setup Wizard and command line can write files to the Magento file system.

```
cd /var/www/html/<magento install directory>
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chown -R :www-data . // Ubuntu
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 2):

Use these commands to overwrite permissions.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                 // 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                 // 755 permission for directory 
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;             // 777 permission for var folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Give full control (read/write/execute) to var directory.

`sudo chmod -R 777 var`

You can also try running command using sudo

`sudo php bin/magento {your command}`